# MODBUS (RTU mode) CRC calculation... what's wrong? it's a misprint of the DPS5020 user manual?

Tags: crc, modbus

I am analyzing the MODBUS protocol (rs232 com port) used in the DPS5020 power supply module and I cannot understand the CRC calculation method in RTU mode (page 3) https://cloud.kyme32.ro/ftp_backup/DPS5020%20PC%20Software(2017.11.04)/DPS5020%20CNC%20Communication%20%20Protocol%20V1.2.pdf.
In the first example on page 4 for sending bytes 1, 3,0,2,0,2 the value CRC = 65CB (Hex) is indicated (2 byte swapped).
I've also tried several CRC calculators online but can't find the right value.
I also did a step-by-step diagram of the calculation and the right rotation of the bits, but the values ​​do not return to me.
Is it necessary to use all the bytes of the frame (6) for the calculation or only the data values ​​(4)? I have tried both without success...
Could you kindly put a little diagram of how the calculation is done and the return values ​​step by step (16 bit xor with A001 value, rotate right yes / no ... etc)?
I know that in the end you have to swap the 2 bytes between them but the single values ​​do not come back to me anyway.
Or is it simply a misprint of the manual?

Comment: Entering `010300020002` [here](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/) generates the expected CRC-16, `65 CB` , and `01030002000265CB` is successfully parsed, as an RTU Request, in [this parser](https://rapidscada.net/modbus/ModbusParser.aspx) (if you change the CRC it will fail). Section 6.2.2 in [this spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) includes a worked example which may help. If you edit your question and add your attempt someone may spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All bytes in the frame are used in the CRC calculation.

Here is a C implementation of the CRC, which should answer your question about exactly what to shift and exclusive-or when:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t crc16modbus_bit(uint16_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001 : crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

(The initial CRC value is returned when called with `mem` equal to `NULL`.)

Comment: Thank you very much.. the linked document is perfect for me...
i worked whit a bit pattern/schema but i'm wrong ...
At page 41 of the linked document there is the perfect schema / calculation flow
thank you again and excuse me for my bad english...
regards